# Mini Rocket Explanation?

Tags: pressure, rocket-science

What's the explanation to This homemade rocket?
I need an explanation including pressure and some kind of explanation to "reactions" If you can do this Ill be really grateful, Thanks a ton.

http://www.metacafe.com/watch/828065/incredible_mini_rocket/

Comment: What do you think is happening?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about physics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The burning of the match head (or anything really), produces a large quantity of hot gas. The foil wrapped around the match head traps the gas. The needle is used to create a small vent that allows the gas to escape in only one direction. Because the vent is so small, the gas released by burning the match needs to leave at high speed due to the large amount of gas created by the burning match head. This creates a rocket.

A description and explanation with diagrams can be found here: https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/TRC/Rockets/match_rocket.html